# S#arp Architecture :: IoC with Custom MembershipProvider

Tags: ioc-container, s#arp-architecture

I´m using the lastest S#arp Architecture version...

In my project, I´m implementing a Custom MembershipProvider...

First question, Where is the right place to put it?  I choose **Core** project...

Second question, How work IoC with custom MembershipProvider?

Here is my code :

```c#
public class AdminMemberProvider : MembershipProvider
{
...
       private readonly IRepository<Customer> userRepository;

       public AdminMemberProvider(IRepository<Customer> __userRepository)
       {
           Check.Require(__userRepository != null, "userRepository may not be null");
           userRepository = __userRepository;
       }
...
}


public class AdminRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    private readonly IRepository<Customer> userRepository;   

    public AdminRoleProvider(IRepository<Customer> __userRepository): base()
    {
        Check.Require(__userRepository != null, "userRepository may not be null");

        userRepository = __userRepository;
    }
    ...
}
```

When I tried to execute my project I got the error:

**Parser Error Message: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.**

```xml
<add name="AdminRoleProvider" type="MalCat.Shop.Core.Membership.AdminRoleProvider, MalCat.Shop.Core" />
```

Should the IoC not handle this ? What am I supposed to do to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the first question, to me it doesn't feel it belongs in core(if I am not mistaken the membership provider is in System.Web), I would put it with a web related project.

The second question has been discussed before on the sharp architecture group, perhaps this thread will be of use:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sharp-architecture

Mauricio Scheffer wrote a blog post about this recently:
http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/11/windsor-managed-membershipproviders.html

Answer (score 0):

I would put it in the Service Layer (ApplicationServices). It is a service after all. And it will make use of your UserRepositories in the Data Layer.